# How to persist Topics ID, Which marked as completed in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

**I want to track completed Topics list in TableView**

> I have set delegate which confirms to tableView topic mark as completed

```
protocol TopicDetialVCDelegate: class {
func hasBeenCompletedTopic()
```

}

> TableViewVC

```
func hasBeenCompletedTopic() {
    isPerformedDelegate = true
    if !completedTopicIdArray.contains(completedTopicId) {
        completedTopicIdArray.append(completedTopicId)
    }
    print("completed Topics \(completedTopicIdArray)")
    print("TopicVC: Completed Topics total: \(completedTopicIdArray.count)")
}
```

> This is working, but i want to persist always mark as completed which already marked

[image: sample image]

> Here is code of CellForRowAt

```
  if isPerformedDelegate {
        for _ in 0...completedTopicIdArray.count {
            if completedTopicIdArray.contains(filteredTopicArray[indexPath.row].id!) {
                cell.topicCompletedTickImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tick")
            }
        }
    }
```

**What i want**

There should be a array which get all completed topics idz, and on every run of app checks if cell indexpath contain topicID show Tick image

> I can use UserDefaults like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forkey: "abc")
```

*but problem is array will reinitialize on run of app again*

> like so in ViewWillDisappear

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(completedTopicIdArray, forKey: "completedTopics")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

> accessing in ViewDidLoad

```
let topics = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "completedTopics")
    print(topics as? [Int] ?? [Int]())
```

Comment: UserDefaults isn't the best data store to use for anything beyond simple settings (as its name implies).  You should look at something like Core Data; You would then store a number of `Topic` entities, each with an `isCompleted` bool property.  However, your problem seems to be how you load the data back from user defaults when the app starts - Can you show that code?

Comment: Where are you get/set `completedTopicIdArray` to UserDefaults?

Comment: @TraiNguyen in ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappar

Comment: @Paulw11 this is i am asking that how to persist data, i can access on app starts, its a array so therefor i give an example of UserDefaults. anyway so i should make an entity with topic id and iscompleted bool type?

Comment: @UmerKhan can you post source code with load/save `completedTopicIdArray` to UserDefaults?

Comment: @TraiNguyen added please checkout

Comment: where do you initialise "completedTopicIdArray" ?

Comment: @ibnetariq inside tableview class, and this is problem  because every time viewDidLoad array re initialized

Comment: check if your "viewWillDisappear" is getting called properly

Comment: This code is working fine for me.
var completedTopicIdArray = [Int]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "completedTopics") as? [Int] {
            completedTopicIdArray = array
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UserDefaults.standard.set([1, 2, 5], forKey: "completedTopics")
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have been solved this Problem Using CoreData, want to share**

> Declare empty array

```
 var completedTopicsIdPersistArray: [Int]    = [Int]()
```

> CoreData Method for Creating

func persistIdIntoCoreData() {

```
    guard let appDelegate    = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ComTopicDB", in: managedObjectContext)
        else {
            print("Entity Not Found")
            return
    }

    let topicIdz = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
                topicIdz.setValue(completedTopicId, forKey: "topicId")

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unable to save into CoreData: \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

> CoreData Method for Retrieving

```
func retrieveIdFromCoreData() {

    guard let appDelegate    = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest         = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "ComTopicDB")

    do {
        let topicIdz = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for id in topicIdz {

            let unwrapId = id.value(forKey: "topicId") as! Int
            if !completedTopicsIdPersistArray.contains(unwrapId) {
                completedTopicsIdPersistArray.append(unwrapId)
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Found issue during retrieve id from CoreData:\(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

> Calling inside of delegate method, which confirms topic completed

```
func hasBeenCompletedTopic() {
    isPerformedDelegate = true
    if !completedTopicIdArray.contains(completedTopicId) {
        completedTopicIdArray.append(completedTopicId)
        persistIdIntoCoreData()
    }
    print("completed Topics \(completedTopicIdArray)")
    print("TopicVC: Completed Topics total: \(completedTopicIdArray.count)")
    retrieveIdFromCoreData()
}
```

> and finally CellForRowAt Method

```
if completedTopicsIdPersistArray.contains(filteredTopicArray[indexPath.row].id!) {
        cell.topicCompletedTickImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tick")
    }
```

> Finally call inside ViewWillAppear, because it comes from topicDetailVC back

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
    retrieveIdFromCoreData()
}
```

**Now all topics will show Tick icon, which marked as completed, even terminate and relaunch app**

[image: output]